# $_POST on combobox select

Tags: php, combobox

I have a page with multiple submit buttons and a text input. When the text input is filled and any button is pressed, the page `$_POST`s to itself and I can grab the information and manipulate it again.

However, I wish for the page to $_POST when a combobox selection is chosen **without** pressing any of the submit buttons.

Is this possible using PHP or must I use javascript to triger a $_POST call?

Comment: You will need javascript indeed. I suggest using jQuery .change() event.

Comment: When you see your page php has already stopped running. So you can do it with Javascript

Comment: @MarcoMura Yes, but you can use a submit button and use $_POST to reload the page. Im asking can you do this with only HTML / PHP on a combobox, like you can with buttons or hitting return on textfields.

Comment: You need onchange (javascript) to launch something, ajax, post submitting, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `onchange=""` property in the HTML
so in html inside the form you do:

```
<select onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
  <option value="1">num1</option>
  <option value="2">num2</option>
  <option value="3">num3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<select name="type" class="type">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>

$(".type").change(function(){

$(".formclass").submit();

});
```